# Arduino Won't Work With Sensors - Pulsates 1/HIGH when not plugged in, constant HIGH/1 when plugged in

Tags: sensors, clones

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpAHdO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried to do a simple project where a 8x8 matrix lamp would display something different depending on whether or not a sensor outputted high/low.

There was no trouble getting the matrix lamp to work, as I wanted, but the sensor kept outputting 1, regardless if it was plugged in or not.

This is the code I used, but when I plugged in the sensor it would display 1/high continuously, and when I removed all wires from the sensor, the lamp would light occasionally and the monitor would display 1 as the movStat value.

The LED lamp is connected directly to the breadboard via. digital pin 4.

I am considering buying a new Arduino, but I would like to get a second hand opinion before I spend money on it.

I am using a PIR sensor model HC SR501:
[image]

```cpp
int movSens = 3;
int ledPin = 4;
int movStat = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Sensor Setup
    pinMode(movSens, INPUT);
    //LED Setup
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    delay(1000);

    Serial.println(movSens);

    movStat = digitalRead(movSens);

    if (movStat == HIGH) { //If motion is detected, activate LED
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }

    Serial.println(movStat);
}
```

Comment: Please show your schematic and code if you want any help.

Comment: Alternatively request that your existing SO question be migrated to here.

Comment: @Majenko I have added the original question now :)

Comment: Do you have a resistor with your LED?

Comment: @Majenko yes, but the LED isn't the problem.

The problem is, that the Arduino randomly outputs a value such that movSens becomes 1/HIGH, activating the LED, even though there is absolutely no sensor or anything connected to the Arduino.

And if I connect the sensor, even with 15 seconds of calibration, it will just remain on HIGH/1. This also happened with another sensor I had.

Comment: With no sensor you can expect a random value - you have a floating input. That tells you the Arduino is fine. It sounds more like the sensor is bad or not wired correctly.

Comment: @Majenko THat is good to hear. But, the sensor will still activate, and then remain at 1.

This has nothing to do with my code, but has something to do with the sensor itself? It is wired such, that looking at the pins, the right hand pin is wired to 5V, middle output and left GND, i.e according to the schmeatics.

Comment: Sounds likely. Can you show your actual wiring (photograph will do)?

Comment: @Majenko I have added schematics.

Comment: the documentation states that the output is 3.3 V when motion is detected and 0 V otherwise .... if you are using a 5 V arduino, then use the analog input for the sensor

Comment: @jsotola, Mega will read 3.3 V as HIGH

Comment: @jsotola Tried using A1, nothing changed.

Comment: use a voltmeter to verify the output of the sensor

Comment: Could it have something to do with the trigger or not trigger jumper setting.